# Simple_html_dom find table with custom style

Tags: php, styles, find, simple-html-dom

How to find table with style? I know it have style attr:

> style="border: 1px  solid  #aaaaaa; border-collapse: collapse; width: 600px; background: #ffffff; text-align: center; margin-top: 10px;"

but how to use it with "find"?

I tried:

```
$scrap['content']->find('table[style*=border: 1px solid #aaaaaa; border-collapse: collapse; width: 600px; background: #ffffff; text-align: center; margin-top: 10px;]');
```

but its not working

Answer (score 0):

It works for me:

```
require_once('simple_html_dom.php');

$html = <<<EOF
<table>foo</table>
<table style="border: 1px solid #aaaaaa; border-collapse: collapse; width: 600px; background: #ffffff; text-align: center; margin-top: 10px;">bar</table>
EOF;

$doc = str_get_html($html);
echo $doc->find('table[style*=border: 1px solid #aaaaaa; border-collapse: collapse; width: 600px; background: #ffffff; text-align: center; margin-top: 10px;]', 0)->text();
//=> bar
```